# Replace not working python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to loop through a file and replace all instances of several things.. It's working SOME of the time, but it's missing values that it correctly replaced earlier in the file and I have no idea why it won't work every time.

```
with open("myfile", "rt") as filein:
with open("mynewfile", "wt") as fileout:
    for line in filein:
        fileout.write(line.replace('a', 'b'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('c', 'd'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('e', 'f'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('g', 'h'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('i', 'j'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('k', 'l'))
print("Done")
```

Comment: The replace method does not mutate the string it returns a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace method does not mutate the string it returns a new one
try this

```
with open("myfile", "rt") as filein, open("mynewfile", "wt") as fileout
        for line in filein:
            line = line.replace('a', 'b')
            fileout.write(line)
            line = line.replace('c', 'd')
            fileout.write(line)
            ...
```

or better

```
list_replace = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ...]
with open("myfile", "rt") as filein, open("mynewfile", "wt") as fileout
        for line in filein:
            for t in list_replace:
                line = line.replace(*t)
            fileout.write(line)
```

Update based on the comments

```
list_replace = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ...]
with open("myfile", "rt") as filein, open("mynewfile", "wt") as fileout
        for line in filein:
            tmp = line[36:]
            for t in list_replace:
                tmp = tmp.replace(*t)
            fileout.write(line[:36] + tmp)
```

Comment: I did not get it , could please explain more

Comment: like this, so it's replacing SOME of the values but missing others even if it caught it earlier
line1: original
line2: original, original
line3: original, replaced
line4: replaced, replaced
line5: replaced

Comment: it looks like it worked!! thank you so much! what did that change do? it looks like all you did was move the 2nd open to the same line as the first, is there a way to make it start looking to replace at a certain point in the line? there is an ID before the part i'm replacing and it looks like the numbers i'm replacing are in some of those ids

Comment: Yep, before it writes the line after each replace operation

Comment: I'm really new to this, sorry for all the questions.. I tried line = line[36:].replace(*t) and nothing wrote

Comment: No, it runs through just fine but it doesn't do anything when I try to start at that position

Comment: Make sure that the lines length is greater than 36, cause if they are not python will write empty values

Comment: each one is 45+ characters, but nothing is writing. Am I putting it in wrong?

Comment: try this line[36:] = line[36:].replace(*t)

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment is what i get back

Comment: It works perfectly, you rock thank you so much for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Cannot replicate your problem in Python 3. The following works just fine:

```
with open("myfile", "rt") as filein, open("mynewfile", "wt") as fileout:
    for line in filein:
        fileout.write(line.replace('a', 'b'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('c', 'd'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('e', 'f'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('g', 'h'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('i', 'j'))
        fileout.write(line.replace('k', 'l'))
print("Done")
```

You have to account for the presence of a `\n` at the end of `filein` though, so check for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing out 6 lines to fileout for every line you read in from filein. Each new line only replaces 1 character, not all of them.

If you're trying to replace everything in the line, try the following. *multi_replace* takes a list of search strings, and replace strings, then iterates over them to replace them individually on each line.

```
def multi_replace(line, searchlist, replacelist):
   for i, j in zip(searchlist, replacelist):
     line = line.replace(i, j)
   return line

with open("myfile", "rt") as filein:
  with open("mynewfile", "wt") as fileout:
    for line in filein:
        fileout.write(multi_replace(line, ['a','c','e','g','i','k'],['b','d','f','h','j','l']))
print("Done")
```